# Dell Audio Headphone Jack and Line Out playing sound through at the same time

Tags: sound, dell, pulseaudio, headphones, audio-jack

So I have a Dell AIO with Dell Audio drivers installed, and I use PulseAudio Volume Control (pavucontrol) to control general sound. I normally use my left headphone jack (TRRS) for my earphones, and my analog Line Out (TRS) jack at the back for my speaker system. When I installed Ubuntu 17.04 just recently, I plugged in my earphones as a headset, but the sound plays through both the Line out and left jack at the same time. It is quite annoying and I tried to fix it using `pavucontrol`, but it still has that problem. Help?

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use hdajackretask to override what each jack does.

You can do so by installing alsa-tools-gui and playing with the functionality of your jacks.

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-tools-gui
hdajackretask
```

You can set your pins to do what you want and then click on apply now. If it works they way you want it to, you can then simply click on Install boot override and it will stay that way.

Comment: Hmm. No matter what, it would either still let sound play through both lines or disable them all together. For now, I will stick to having a killswitch for my ext. DAC/AMP when I use my headphone jack. :P